# Poco C++ HTTPResponse how can i get the entire header map of a response?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

So here is the [class](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPResponse.html)
I need to cache the entire header map. So I figured I should extract it some how.

How can i do this, do i need to iterate them like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991496/poco-cnet-http-get-headers-from-response), or can I get them all at once?

I intend to store the header map in a cache like :

```
       LRUPersistentCache<string, pair<HeaderMap, string > > *clientCache;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create NameValueCollection (it's a map-like HTTPResponse's parent) from HTTPResponse:

```
HTTPResponse response;
// ...
NameValueCollection nvc(response);
LRUPersistentCache<string, NameValueCollection> clientCache(100);
clientCache.add("myresponse", nvc);
// ...
```